# StandardTokenizer overrides final method setReader.(Ljava/io/Reader;)V

Tags: java, lucene, classloader

I'm trying to use [Lucene StandardTokenizer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html) as in the code below:

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // line 28 goes below
        StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_40);
        // the rest is irrelevant
    }
}
```

It is throwing `VerifyError`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: class org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardTokenizer overrides final method setReader.(Ljava/io/Reader;)V
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at lt.App.main(App.java:28)
```

Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have 2 different versions of lucene in your classpath?

The method `setReader(...)` was added to `StandardTokenizer` in the 4.0.0-BETA version. But it was later removed from `StandardTokenizer` and made final in `Tokenizer` before the 4.0.0 release version. So I you may have the 4.0.0-BETA version of the **lucene-analyzers-common** jar in your classpath and the 4.0.0 release version of **lucene-core** jar.

[LUCENE-4343](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-4343) is probably the issues that changed this.